# JavaScript fuction calling dynamically className

Tags: javascript, jquery

my goal is that when the user clicks the checkbox, it will count how many checked inputs there is with the same `class name`. I'm trying to send the `var e` into the counting function but I'm not sure about the right syntax. When I replace the `e` in here:  `var n = $( '.e:checked' ).length;` with a className it is working. But I need it to be dynamic.

**Edit for the question:
How can I get value from the console log to var in PHP?**

View

```
<br>
<label>
    <input onclick="b(this.className)" 
           class="tuesdayMorBar" 
           type="checkbox"
           name="worker_name[]" 
           value="<?php echo $shift['fullname'];?>" />
```

Javascript

```js
function b(e) {
    var countChecked = function() {
        var n = $('.e:checked').length;
        alert(n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!");
    };
    countChecked();

    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);
}
```

Comment: replace the inside of $() with a string literal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: `$('.e:checked')` should be `$('.' + e + ':checked')`

Comment: Why do you attach an on-click event inside the function which is used in `onclick`?

Comment: Remove `onclick="b(this.className)"`. Define `countChecked` at global level. Set click event with `$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);`. Then you can use `this.className` inside `countChecked`. It will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `onclick="b(this.className)"`. Define `countChecked` at global level. Set click event with `$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);`. Then you can use `this.className` inside `countChecked`. It will work fine.
View

```
<br>
<label>
    <input class="tuesdayMorBar" 
           type="checkbox"
           name="worker_name[]" 
           value="<?php echo $shift['fullname'];?>" />
```

Javascript

```js
var countChecked = function() {
    var n = $('.' + this.className + ':checked').length;
    alert(n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!");
};

$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I get value from the console log to var in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can query for selectors with specific classes and attributes using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Try with this:

```
function b() {
  var checkedInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input.your-class-name[type='checkbox']:checked");
  alert((checkedInputs.length === 1 ? "is" : "are") + " checked!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a working snippet for your problem @Victoria's Secret. Comments are mentioned in the snippet itself. See if this resolves your issue.

```js
function b(e) {

  let totalChecked = 0; // initialize the variable with 0;

  $("input[type=checkbox]." + e).each(function() { // check every checkbox with class e(e has className)
    //console.log($(this));
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) { // check if checkboxed is checked
      totalChecked++; // increment every time
    }
  });
  alert(`class ${e}: ${totalChecked}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><label><input onchange="b(this.className)" class="kaka" type="checkbox"
 name="worker_name[]" value="kaka1" />kaka1
 <input onchange="b(this.className)" class="kaka" type="checkbox"
 name="worker_name[]" value="kaka2" />kaka2
 <input onchange="b(this.className)" class="kaka" type="checkbox"
 name="worker_name[]" value="kaka3" />kaka3
 <br><br>
 <input onchange="b(this.className)" class="lala" type="checkbox"
 name="worker_name[]" value="lala1" />lala1
 <input onchange="b(this.className)" class="lala" type="checkbox"
 name="worker_name[]" value="lala2" />lala2
 <br><br>
 <input onchange="b(this.className)" class="jaja" type="checkbox"
 name="worker_name[]" value="jaja1" />jaja1
 <input onchange="b(this.className)" class="jaja" type="checkbox"
 name="worker_name[]" value="jaja2" />jaja2
```