# JavaScript objects array inserting new one and console log

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a dynamic objects array (like key:value).
I want to insert each key(the class name that was clicked on) and the value(the number of checked). 
I wrote the console.log so I could get the value from the array in PHP.
The problem is: it won't insert a new object in that way.

```
var countChecked = function() {
    var checked = {};

    var n = $( '.'+ this.className + ':checked' ).length;
    checked.push({'this.className',n});
    console.log(checked);
    alert( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
};

countChecked();
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: _"I know the syntax is bad."_ - Then fix it, preferable before you post your question.

Comment: `checked` is an object, so instead of `checked.push({'this.className',n});` use `checked[this.className] = n;` as `push` will throw an error because it is an array method

Comment: ... also `checked` is recreated for each function call so it will always contain only one key-value pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, this snippet will work for you. I've also taken reference from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62448211/javascript-fuction-calling-dynamically-classname). I've explained the code in the snippet itself. See if it helps you.

```js
let checkedArr = []; // initialize the variable(type = array) to global scope.

function b(e) { // called every time a the checkbox is clicked

  let totalChecked = 0; // initialize the variable with 0;

  $("input[type=checkbox]." + e).each(function() { // check every checkbox with class e(e has className)

    //console.log($(this));
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) { // check if checkboxed is checked

      totalChecked++; // increment every time

    }
  });

  // find if class already exists -- returns the index of matched element and -1 for no match
  let existIndex = checkedArr.findIndex((item) => item.class == e);

  console.clear();
  // console.log(existIndex);

  if (existIndex != -1) { // if class exists in array, update its value

    checkedArr[existIndex].checked = totalChecked;

  } else { // if not insert the value as an object

    checkedArr.push( {class: e, checked: totalChecked} );
  
  }
  
  $('.some_class').val(JSON.stringify(checkedArr)); // convert it to string and assign it to the input field 
  
  alert($('.some_class').val());
  console.log(checkedArr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input onchange="b(this.className)" class="kaka" type="checkbox" name="worker_name[]" value="kaka1" />kaka1
<input onchange="b(this.className)" class="kaka" type="checkbox" name="worker_name[]" value="kaka2" />kaka2
<input onchange="b(this.className)" class="kaka" type="checkbox" name="worker_name[]" value="kaka3" />kaka3
&emsp;&emsp;

<input onchange="b(this.className)" class="lala" type="checkbox" name="worker_name[]" value="lala1" />lala1
<input onchange="b(this.className)" class="lala" type="checkbox" name="worker_name[]" value="lala2" />lala2
&emsp;&emsp;

<input onchange="b(this.className)" class="jaja" type="checkbox" name="worker_name[]" value="jaja1" />jaja1
<input onchange="b(this.className)" class="jaja" type="checkbox" name="worker_name[]" value="jaja2" />jaja2

<!-- Make this ↓↓ hidden -- here only for demo -->
<input type="text" name="hidden_field" class="some_class" value="" />
```

Now as you can see, the input field has the value of `checkeArr`. Then, in your `controller` you can get the value as -

```
$hidden = $this->input->post('hidden_field'); // name of your hidden field
$hidden = json_decode($hidden); // convert it back to its original form

print_r($hidden);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [class] => kaka
            [checked] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [class] => lala
            [checked] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [class] => jaja
            [checked] => 2
        )

)
```

You can now use `foreach` to get its value use it however you want.

Comment: That is great, Thank you. Now, do you know maybe how can I access this value in console log from on the client-side in HTML or on the server-side in PHP?

Comment: You're using a form, right? Why not make a hidden input field and assign it a value equal to `checkedArr`, then you can use this field to access its value by `$this->input->post('hidden_field_name');`

Comment: I am using a form, but I need this value for a for loop, so I could print certain inputs according to the checked number.  What do you mean, by `$this->input->post->('hidden_field_name');`

Comment: @Victoria'sSecret I've updated the answer to fit your needs

Comment: I am checking it right now, Thank you, I appreciate it.